# probability of rank for n iid random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Denote the $i$th order statistic as $X_{(i)}$, then what is $\Pr(X_i = X_{(j)})$ for some $i, j = 1,...,n$ and iid $X_1, ..., X_n$?

I think this is what rank tests are based on but I'm stuck on making any progress.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $n$ real-valued continuous random variables which are *identically and independently* distributed, then that means there is *no bias* as to which variable is realised as which order statistic.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_i=X_{(j)}) & = \mathsf P(X_1=X_{(j)}) \\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(X_2=X_{(j)}) \\[1ex] & \vdots \\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(X_n=X_{(j)}) \\[1ex] & = \frac{1}{n}\end{align}$$

Note that this doesn't *quite* hold if there is a non-zero measure of 'ties' (such as for discrete distributions).   In such a case the events have equal probability, but are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Any way to establish this rigorously though? I've tried to use the total probability formula but got stuck again.

Comment: Would this work? $\mathbf{P} (X_1 = X_{(j)}) = \int \mathbf{P} (X_{(j)} = x \mid X_1 = x)\text{d} F (x)$, now the conditional probability $\mathbf{P} (A \mid X_1 = x)$is defined using $P_{X_1}$ and the common probability space only, which is the same for all $X_i$ since they are identically distributed.

Comment: @simonzack Well... yes, but that is: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X_i=X_{(j)}) & = \binom{n-1}{j-1} \mathsf P(X_k<X_i\mid k\neq i)^{j-1}\mathsf P(X_k\geq X_i\mid k\neq i)^{n-j}
\\[1ex] & = \binom{n-1}{j-1} \int_{x\in\mathcal X} \mathsf P(X_k<x\mid k\neq i, X_i=x)^{j-1}\;\mathsf P(X_k\geq x\mid X_i=x, k\neq i)^{n-j} \;F(\operatorname dx) 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks but how do you arrive at the first step? Are $1(X_i \ge X_1)$ and $1(X_i \ge X_2)$ independent?

Comment: Yes, for **iid** random variables, @simonzack

Comment: But take $X_1, X_2, X_i \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$, then $\Pr(X_i \ge X_1) = 3\cdot 0.5^2$ and $\Pr(X_i \ge X_1, X_i \ge X_2) = 5\cdot 0.5^3$.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you see it more easily:

Imagine that you write the order statistics on balls and put them in a bag, mix them up and draw them out one at a time in order to pair the observation numbers (the "$i$" in your notation) with those values. So label the first ball drawn "observation 1", the second "observation 2" and so on.

What's the probability that the ball with $j$th order statistic is drawn first? Drawn 14th? Drawn last?